# Replace "-from" with "this" in the begining of line

Tags: sed, grep, awk

I want to replace "-from" with "this" in the begining of line. This should happen when that line has 'R' at the end and line above it has "D" at the end.

For example for the block shown below:

```
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/D   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/R   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/K   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/L   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/G   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/R
```

the output should look like:

```
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/D   
-this XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/R   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/K   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/L   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/G   
-from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/R
```

Anything is fine, `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

- When the previous line has `D` at the end,

  - and when the current line has `R` at the end,

    - then the first word (`-from`) must be replaced by `-this`.

`awk` script:

```
# if the prev. line ended with D, and the current with R, replace first word
# optionally add && $1 == "-from"
has_d && /R$/ { $1 = "-this"; }
# print the current line, pretend that d is not matched yet
{ print; has_d = 0; }
# if line ends with D, set flag
/D$/ { has_d = 1; }
```

One liner:

```
awk 'has_d&&/R$/{$1="-this"}{print;has_d=0}/D$/{has_d=1}' yourfile
```

Comment: Goodness gracious, worked like a charm:)

Comment: @RanaKhan - make sure to mark this as the accepted answer so others know your Q has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`:

```
sed '/D$/{N;/R$/s/\n-from/\n-this/}' your_file
```

Expanded with comments:

```
sed ' /D$/{                          # If the current line ends in D
            N;                       # Append the next line to the pattern space
            /R$/s/\n-from/\n-this/   # If you find R at end-of-line, substitute
      }' your_file
```